# expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'compareWeight'

Tags: c

I created a class 'compareWeight' and I inherited it in another class 'compareWeight_graph' but I keep getting an error about expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'compareWeight' when compiling

Code:

```
int compareWeight(Edge *edge1, Edge *edge2)
{
    return edge1->weight - edge2->weight;
}

int compareWeight_graph(int v, compareWeight **edges)
{
    int n = triangular_number(v - 1);
    int i, j, k;
    *edges = malloc(n * sizeof(compareWeight));
    if (edges != NULL) {
        for (i = 0, k = 0; i < v - 1; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < v; j++) {
                (*edges)[k].src = i;
                (*edges)[k].dst = j;
                (*edges)[k].weight = k + 1;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: You are using the same name `compareWeight` for a type and for a function. This is not a good idea.

Comment: And what is this "class" thing you speak of? This is C code.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker Sorry, I'm just learning C and I guess I mixed up the names.

Comment: @AnT how do you recommend I fix this. Thanks.

Comment: You fix it by providing [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we have some clue what the type `compareWeight` is and can explain that `sizeof(compareWeight)` is nothing but `sizeof (a_pointer)` (likely not what you intended). You could make progress by changing your *Function* name to  `int compareEdgeWeight(..)` (though C-style generally avoids *camelCase* variable and function names in favor of all lowercase...)

Answer (score 0):

You define `sizeof(compareWeight)` as a function name and a type, too.
Change your function name or type name to other.
Example, change type name from `compareWeight` to `compareWeight_t`